# List comprehension with conditional function inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, list-comprehension

I want to write list comprehension with conditional function inside. This what i have so far

```
more_grades = [0.0, 50.0, 49.9, 79.0, 101.0, 65.0, 54.2, 48.2, 78.9]
def grade_classification(grade):
        if grade < 40:
            result = 'fail'
        elif grade >= 40 and grade < 50:
            result = 'Pass'
        elif grade >= 50 and grade < 60:
            result = '2:2'
        elif grade >= 60 and grade < 70:
            result= '2:1'
        elif grade >= 70:
            result = 'First'
        else:
            result = 'unknown grade'
        return result
studen_classficatin = [result for result in more_grades if grade_classification(result)]
print(studen_classficatin)
```

The output should be = ['Fail', '2:2', 'Pass', 'First', 'First', '2:1', '2:2', 'Pass', 'First'] but from the code above its giving me = [0.0, 50.0, 49.9, 79.0, 101.0, 65.0, 54.2, 48.2, 78.9]
I dont know what i am doing wrong. Please any suggestion?

Comment: Don't you mean `[grade_classification(result) for result in more_grades]`?

Comment: `grade_classification()` always returns a truthy value. Why are you treating it like a conditional?

Comment: You don't need a conditional. You are simply mapping each grade value to a string description of that grade.

Comment: If in doubt about writing a comprehension just write it as a for loop appending to a list which is initially empty. That way you can debug it whereas list comprehensions are undebuggable, as you’ve found. One-liners can be over-rated.

Comment: @balmy IMO, this is a clear-cut use for a list comprehension. Not knowing how to apply the list comprehension does not make it overrated.

Comment: @chepner - yes, if you know what you’re doing and how to test/get it working. But if you don’t then a for loop is much easier to write and debug. And you do see questions from people who seem to think one-liner comprehension is the objective, rather than the real objective which is solving the problem with a program that works, and can be debugged and maintained.

Comment: … as @rizwan’s comment on one of the answers to his homework show. I wonder how he’ll score?

Comment: Again: You are in my class; this is a class exercise. You can ask me. You have not asked me.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this instead:

```
studen_classficatin = [grade_classification(result) for result in more_grades]
```

The trailing `if` will determine whether or not an element should be added to the list, not "transform" the element itself

Comment: thank you so much yeah it worked. can you elaborate what i was doing wrong? i mean why my code was printing the same list of input plz? trying to learn the concepts behind it

Comment: In plain English, your version is saying: "for each result in more_grades, add result to the list *IF* the return value of grade_classification(result) is a truthy value". Now, a non-empty string is a truthy value in python, and since your function always returns a non-empty string, all elements get added.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi sorry one more question plz, if i wanted add condition for above list e.g i want to count how may students have been failed which is one. I have failed_students = [len(result = 'Fail')]. I am pretty sure its wrong.

Comment: I'd try to avoid using strings to represent the grades since it can be quite error-prone, but one could for instance do `Counter(studen_classficatin)["fail"]` (`Counter` comes from the collections package) or, building upon what you had, `len([x for x in studen_classficatin if x.lower() == "fail"])`. The `lower()` isn't really needed, but it's good practice to normalize the strings before doing any comparison (unless it should be case-sensitive, of course)

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do list comprehension, instead you can apply `map` to your list to call a function on each entry of the list. The result will be an iterator that consists of the returned value for each value in your previous list:

```
studen_classficatin = map(grade_classification, more_grades)
```

`map` returns an iterator, so it doesn't *actually* do anything until you iterate over the list. If you want to print it, call `list` on the iterator to exhaust it:

```
studen_classficatin = list(map(grade_classification, more_grades))
```

Comment: I am doing an exercise and i have to solve it with list comprehension using function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is this:

`studen_classficatin = [result for result in more_grades if grade_classification(result)]`

Which, because non-empty strings are *truthy*, is the same as:

`studen_classficatin = [result for result in more_grades if True]`

Which is the same as:

`studen_classficatin = [result for result in more_grades]`

which is the same as just copying `more_grades`.